# Cannot repaint new elements without repainting old ones

Tags: java, frame, repaint

Here is my problem :

I have made a program that draws squares at random locations, its a tad crude but it works.
However the problem is that it will not repaint properly, I don't know where but somewhere in the code I made a mistake.

This causes the following to happen : I tell the application to draw 5 squares it does so but then when I tell it to draw 6 it will draw the previous 5 + 6.

The code is listed below in two parts RandomSquares and DrawField :

```
public class RandomSquares extends JPanel {

private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Squares");
private static DrawField f;
private static JButton button = new JButton("Make squares");
private static final JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
private static int amount = 0;

private static void prepareFrame() {
    //knoppen

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                System.out.println(amount);
                amount = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
                f = new DrawField(amount);
                frame.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                frame.repaint();


        }

    });

    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    Listener l = new Listener(); 
    frame.addKeyListener(l);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);

}

public static class Listener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
            //unused
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
                System.out.println("woot!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            //unused
        }       

}


public static void run() {
    f = new DrawField(amount);
    prepareFrame();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

public class DrawField extends JComponent {

```
private int amount;

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public DrawField(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.setSize(540, 380);
    this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {


                g.fillRect(r.nextInt(getWidth()), r.nextInt(getHeight()),
                        20, 20);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Painting methods should only be used for painting, not setting properties of your class.

```
g.fillRect(r.nextInt(getWidth()), r.nextInt(getHeight()), 20, 20);
```

For example if you resize the frame a whole new set of rectangles will be painted at new random locations.

When you invoke super.paintComponent(), the old drawing will be lost and new random rectangle will be created.

Instead your painting code should be based on properties of the class. That is once you create the objects they should be fixed so a repaint of the component does not change the painting, unless you change the properties.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for examples of how to painting with a random number of objects by:

1. keeping a List of objects to paint
2. add objects to a BufferedImage and then just paint the image.

In your case you would invoke the `addRectangles(...)` method for the specified number of rectangle you want to paint. Then the painting code will do the rest.

Edit:

To answer your basic question. In general you need to invoke `super.paintComponent()` to clear the background of a component before doing the custom painting of the component.

The problem is that you are extending `JComponent`, which doesn't not have any default painting code, so the background doesn't get cleared. Two solutions:

1. Extend JPanel instead (JPanel does clear the background).
2. Add custom painting code to your class to clear the background:

Something like:

```
g.setColor( getBackground() );
f.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
// paint rectangle here
```

Comment: Uhm its not important right now that resizing the frame does that, right now what I am looking for is to simply repaint these squares.
I am not looking to list whole arrays of squares and images, there is no importance in it

Comment: `what I am looking for is to simply repaint these squares.` - exactly. But you can't repaint the squares because they will move to a new random location. You can't repaint something if you don't track the information need to repaint a component. If you have a JTextField, you need to know what text is in the text field so you can paint it. You can't just randomly paint characters. So yes it is important to understand this concept now and not later. See edit for solution to your current problem.

Comment: Ah your second solution of making it a Jpanel worked as far as making the background and then some squares.
Except its painting only the first ammount given up, and not any more IE I paint 5 squares but it wont paint 6 or 3. (Still working on understanding your answer)

Comment: @Jackstalkerfear, you should not be creating new components all the time. You just change the property of the component. When you create the frame you add your `DrawField` component to the frame. When you want to change the number of rectangles you invoke the `setAmount(...)` method of your DrawField class. The setAmount() method should then invoke repaint().

Comment: The structure of your code is poor. You should NOT be using static variables and methods the way you are. I suggest you start  with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). The `LabelDemo` example will show you how to better structure your code. Start with a working example and modify it. Learn better techniques now, not later.

Comment: Right i'll think that over and stick to later, sorry still thanks for your answers they have been helpfull

Answer (score 0):

> I tell the application to draw 5 squares it does so but then when I tell it to draw 6 it will draw the previous 5 + 6.

The Component is not being cleared of any previous painting calls - be sure to always call the parent painting method to clear any previous painting. For example:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //custom painting here.
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow, (I am very rookie with this stuff) I havent defined super anywhere so how would drawfield know what super is at this point? Other than himself.

Comment: `super` calls the parent class method. If the class extends `JPanel`, calling `super.paintComponent` calls this method as it is defined in the parent class (or the first parent class in the inheritance hierarchy that implements the method - in the case `JComponent`).

Comment: Well I tried it but I am still having no luck, I guess what your trying to say is that I am now gonna repaint it clean with the super call?
But it remains to draw new squares alongside the old ones ... sorry if I am not understanding this as clearly as I should

Comment: `I guess what your trying to say is that I am now gonna repaint it clean with the super call?` Yes. If the change does not work, please edit your original question with the changes made